# Proof of harmonic series divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

Prove that ∑_(k=1)^∞ 1/k is divergent

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYJ8O.png)

Could anyone possibly help explain my professor’s notation in this proof? Struggling to understand where  S_(2^n-1)≥n/2 came from as well as the manipulation of the sums that follow.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Ben W gave you an answer. I will give you a very simple proof for  the divergence of the harmonic series:

Let $S_n :=1+\frac{1}{2} + ....+ \frac{1}{n} $. Then

$$(*) \quad S_{2n}= S_n +\frac{1}{n+1} +...+ \frac{1}{2n}  \ge S_n +\frac{1}{2n} +...+ \frac{1}{2n}= S_n +\frac{1}{2}.$$

Now assume that $(S_n)$ is convergent, with limit $S$. From $(*)$ we get $S \ge S+\frac{1}{2}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to help him understand his professor's much longer proof, but this is quite nice!

Answer (score 1):

Any sum of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1}f(i)$$
can be written as the double sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=2^{k-1}}^{2^k-1}f(i)$$
To see this, consider a concrete example $n=3$.  Then $2^n-1=7$ so that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^3-1}=f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+f(4)+f(5)+f(6)+f(7)$$
$$=[f(1)]+[f(2)+f(3)]+[f(4)+f(5)+f(6)+f(7)]$$
$$=\sum_{i=2^{1-1}}^{2^1-1}f(i)+\sum_{i=2^{2-1}}^{2^2-1}f(i)+\sum_{i=2^{3-1}}^{2^3-1}f(i)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{i=2^{k-1}}^{2^k-1}f(i)$$
See it now?  Hence we can write
$$S_{2^n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=2^{k-1}}^{2^k-1}\frac{1}{i}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{i=2^{k-1}}^{2^k-1}\frac{1}{i}$$
and the rest should be clear.

P.S. Actually, splitting off the "1" is entirely unnecessary, although not incorrect.

Comment: Great thanks for explaining that it makes sense now. How come S_(2^n-1)≥n/2 in the first sentence of the original proof was chosen as a sufficient to show it is unbounded and divergent? What motivated that specific inequality. Cheers

Comment: It was simply convenient.  Since $n/2\to\infty$ with $n/2\leq S_{2^n-1}$, we get $S_{2^n-1}\to\infty$ as well.  But any expression that goes to $\infty$ will do.